# Varias regresiones con distintos libros de excel

Tags: r, rstudio, machine-learning

Tengo que realizar 54 regresiones entre producción de maíz y lluvias de marzo Abril y Mayo para 54 departamentos de Argentina, cuento con un libro de excel con 3 hojas dónde cada hoja representa las lluvias de cada mes para cada departamento para cada año de la forma que sigue

```
            1969  1970.....
9 de Julio  
25 de Mayo
.
.
```

tengo una hoja como la de arriba para cada mes.
Además tengo otro excel con la producción de maíz para cada departamento y año.
Entonces la pregunta es cómo puedo correr la regresión de la siguiente forma
Y=a0+a1Mar+a2Abr+a3May
para cada departamento y obtener un dataframe con los coeficientes de determinación.

Comment: Es muy amplia tu pregunta, lo que veo es que tienes al menos para abrirla en otras tres preguntas más concretas al menos: (1) Cómo importar un excel de las características que mencionas (2) Como transformar los datos a una estructura que sirva para la regresión (3) Como hacer 54 regresiones con los datos que tienes. El punto 1, tal vez sea el más sencillo y ya lo hayas resuelto, si así fuera, agrega un ejemplo real de los datos, más completo, lo que muestras sirve pero es insuficiente (dónde esta el departamento? las fechas siempre se han escrito de esta forma? cuantos años tiene cada hoja?)

Comment: El punto 2 es el más complejo y sin saber como serán los datos una vez importados, es poco lo que podemos hacer de este lado. El punto 3 se resuelve bastante fácil teniendo los datos en la forma adecuada.

Comment: Muy buena aclaración @PatricioMoracho. Voy a realizar las preguntas por separado porque ni siquiera pude cerrar el punto 1.

Comment: Genial Kev! hay un dicho: "Divide y vencerás". Suerte.